# SOLVED Why is np.empty == np.zeros True, and np.empty == np.zeros False

Tags: python, numpy

New to python and maybe misunderstanding some fundamentals here, but having trouble making sense of the following.

```
print(numpy.empty(3) == numpy.zeros(3))

#Result
[True True True]
```

```
print(numpy.empty(3) == numpy.empty(3))

#Result
[False False False]
```

My original assumption was that .empty array, when the comparison is called, is initialized as .zeros()? But if that's the case, the latter wouldn't make sense.

Comment: [`np.empty`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) does not perform any initialization, and the first comparison to obtain full true is just a coincidence.

Comment: @MechanicPig thanks. I get the first part, could you please elaborate on what a coincidence is specifically?

Comment: NumPy gets memory from a memory allocator. Memory allocators re-use memory that was previously used for other purposes. That memory could be initialized to zero. But someone also could have used the memory to store the string 'Hello World.' Then when `np.empty` gets the memory, it interprets the bytes in that string as a floating point number, and gets some number.

Comment: don't make any assumptions about the np.empty values except shape and dtype.

Comment: The contents could be anything. It could be zeros. It could be ones. It could be the contents of the last array you allocated. It could even be your users' sensitive personal information, so be very careful with it.

Answer (score 2):

The ***numpy.empty*** function creates a new array of the specified shape, but does not initialize it with values. Instead, it leaves the array elements **uninitialized**, which means they can contain random values that were in memory when the array was created.

And ***numpy.zeros*** also creates a new array of the specified shape, but initializes the elements in it as **0.0**

> So when you compare these two arrays, this is what happens:
>
> `[1.23456789e-312, 2.96439388e-323, 2.47032823e-323] == [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`

Comment: thank you, the example is super helpful. Now I understand why `np.empty() == np.empty()` is False. But then why is `np.empty() == np.zeros()` True? If same logic used, shouldn't this also be False unless a coincidence occurs?

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out it was just an environment thing in my Jupyter notebook. I asked the question because I was consistently getting True as an answer on the first check, but when I ran the same on local or online compiler, it gave a different answer. All answers above contributed.

Answer (score -1):

np.empty function creates an array of spaces or storage locations and np.zeros creates an array of zeros. np.empty == np.zeros first tries to assign the values of both functions in order to compare. In the process, since np.empty created just spaces, it automatically saves in the values of the array from np.zeros first and this is why after comparing it says true.
np.empty() == empty() will always be false since they are all to different storage locations.
In order to get this right assign both functions to separate variables so they can save the values in those variables before you compare.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros(3)
b = np.empty(3)
print(a == b)
```